# MYSQL - Display not added item

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to display items that were not added? I want to display the items were not added on the add_tb. The data should be itemcode 2, 4 and 5.

```
item_tb

itemcode  item  
1        monitor
2        mouse
3        keyboard
4        barcode scanner
5        system unit

add_tb

itemcode
1 and 3
```

Comment: Looking at your tables, how can we tell which items were not added? Also, in the `add_tb` does the `itemcode` column really contain values such as `1 and 3`?

Comment: how display all added item ? I guess you can add which you wnat and at last display all items

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` for that as

```
SELECT item FROM item_tb WHERE itemcode 
  NOT IN (SELECT itemcode FROM  add_tb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `add_tb` 
LEFT JOIN `item_tb` ON `add_tb`.itemcode = `item_tb`.itemcode 
WHERE `item_tb`.itemcode IS NULL
```